# Outlook windows desktop task pane add-in opens in new Internet Explorer browser window

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

On some customer setups, we are seeing an issue with task pane type add in - where the index.html target of the task pane opens up in a new Internet explorer browser window instead of loading within the task pane.

Within the browser, the office.js context is not available and so - the app does not load.

This is occurring only on Windows desktop Outlook platform currently and happens on Windows 10, even with the latest Office version 1908

Any pointers on what Office/Internet settings or anything else that could be triggering this issue?

Manifest.xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Created:cb85b80c-f585-40ff-8bfc-12ff4d0e34a9-->
<OfficeApp xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:bt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/officeappbasictypes/1.0"
           xmlns:mailappor="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/appforoffice/1.1" xsi:type="MailApp">
    <Id>12345678-b1a1-123a-bc1b-445f32946c75</Id>
    <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
    <ProviderName>Provider Name</ProviderName>
    <DefaultLocale>en-US</DefaultLocale>
    <DISPLAY_NAME DefaultValue="App Name"/>
    <Description DefaultValue="App description"/>
    <IconUrl DefaultValue="https://customer-pod.domain.com/images/osc_icon_80.png"/>
    <HighResolutionIconUrl DefaultValue="https://customer-pod.domain.com/images/osc_icon_80.png"/>
    <AppDomains>
        <AppDomain>https://login.microsoftonline.com/</AppDomain>
    </AppDomains>
    <Hosts>
        <Host Name="Mailbox"/>
    </Hosts>
    <Requirements>
        <Sets>
            <Set Name="MailBox" MinVersion="1.1"/>
        </Sets>
    </Requirements>
    <FormSettings>
        <Form xsi:type="ItemRead">
            <DesktopSettings>
                <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://customer-pod.domain.com/index.html"/>
                <RequestedHeight>250</RequestedHeight>
            </DesktopSettings>
        </Form>
        <Form xsi:type="ItemEdit">
            <DesktopSettings>
                <SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://customer-pod.domain.com/index.html?rc_channel=COMPOSE"/>
            </DesktopSettings>
        </Form>
    </FormSettings>
    <Permissions>ReadWriteItem</Permissions>
    <Rule xsi:type="RuleCollection" Mode="Or">
        <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Edit"/>
        <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Message" FormType="Read"/>
        <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Edit"/>
        <Rule xsi:type="ItemIs" ItemType="Appointment" FormType="Read"/>
    </Rule>
    <DisableEntityHighlighting>false</DisableEntityHighlighting>
    <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides"
                      xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_0">
        <Hosts>
            <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
                <DesktopFormFactor>
                    <FunctionFile resid="functionFile"/>
                    <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
                        <OfficeTab id="TabDefaultRead">
                            <Group id="oscReadGroup">
                                <Label resid="groupLabel"/>
                                <Tooltip resid="groupTooltip"/>

                                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="oscReadButton">
                                    <Label resid="buttonLabel"/>
                                    <Tooltip resid="buttonTooltip"/>
                                    <Supertip>
                                        <Title resid="superTipTitle"/>
                                        <Description resid="superTipDescription"/>
                                    </Supertip>
                                    <Icon>
                                        <bt:Image size="16" resid="osc_icon_16x16"/>
                                        <bt:Image size="32" resid="osc_icon_32x32"/>
                                        <bt:Image size="80" resid="osc_icon_80x80"/>
                                    </Icon>
                                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                        <SourceLocation resid="residOscHomeUrl"/>
                                    </Action>
                                </Control>
                            </Group>
                        </OfficeTab>
                    </ExtensionPoint>
                    <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
                        <OfficeTab id="TabDefaultCompose">
                            <Group id="oscComposeGroup">
                                <Label resid="groupLabel"/>
                                <Tooltip resid="groupTooltip"/>

                                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="oscComposeButton">
                                    <Label resid="buttonLabel"/>
                                    <Tooltip resid="buttonTooltip"/>
                                    <Supertip>
                                        <Title resid="superTipTitle"/>
                                        <Description resid="superTipDescription"/>
                                    </Supertip>
                                    <Icon>
                                        <bt:Image size="16" resid="osc_icon_16x16"/>
                                        <bt:Image size="32" resid="osc_icon_32x32"/>
                                        <bt:Image size="80" resid="osc_icon_80x80"/>
                                    </Icon>
                                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                        <SourceLocation resid="residOscHomeEditUrl"/>
                                    </Action>
                                </Control>
                            </Group>
                        </OfficeTab>
                    </ExtensionPoint>
                    <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentAttendeeCommandSurface">
                        <OfficeTab id="TabDefaultApptRead">
                            <Group id="oscApptReadGroup">
                                <Label resid="groupLabel"/>
                                <Tooltip resid="groupTooltip"/>

                                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="oscApptReadButton">
                                    <Label resid="buttonLabel"/>
                                    <Tooltip resid="buttonTooltip"/>
                                    <Supertip>
                                        <Title resid="superTipTitle"/>
                                        <Description resid="superTipDescription"/>
                                    </Supertip>
                                    <Icon>
                                        <bt:Image size="16" resid="osc_icon_16x16"/>
                                        <bt:Image size="32" resid="osc_icon_32x32"/>
                                        <bt:Image size="80" resid="osc_icon_80x80"/>
                                    </Icon>
                                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                        <SourceLocation resid="residOscHomeUrl"/>
                                    </Action>
                                </Control>
                            </Group>
                        </OfficeTab>
                    </ExtensionPoint>
                    <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface">
                        <OfficeTab id="TabDefaultApptCompose">
                            <Group id="oscApptComposeGroup">
                                <Label resid="groupLabel"/>
                                <Tooltip resid="groupTooltip"/>
                                <Control xsi:type="Button" id="oscApptComposeButton">
                                    <Label resid="buttonLabel"/>
                                    <Tooltip resid="buttonTooltip"/>
                                    <Supertip>
                                        <Title resid="superTipTitle"/>
                                        <Description resid="superTipDescription"/>
                                    </Supertip>
                                    <Icon>
                                        <bt:Image size="16" resid="osc_icon_16x16"/>
                                        <bt:Image size="32" resid="osc_icon_32x32"/>
                                        <bt:Image size="80" resid="osc_icon_80x80"/>
                                    </Icon>
                                    <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                        <SourceLocation resid="residOscHomeEditUrl"/>
                                    </Action>
                                </Control>
                            </Group>
                        </OfficeTab>
                    </ExtensionPoint>
                </DesktopFormFactor>
            </Host>
        </Hosts>
        <Resources>
            <bt:Images>
                <bt:Image id="osc_icon_16x16" DefaultValue="https://customer-pod.domain.com/css/images/osc_icon_16.png"/>
                <bt:Image id="osc_icon_32x32" DefaultValue="https://customer-pod.domain.com/css/images/osc_icon_32.png"/>
                <bt:Image id="osc_icon_80x80" DefaultValue="https://customer-pod.domain.com/css/images/osc_icon_80.png"/>
            </bt:Images>
            <bt:Urls>
                <bt:Url id="residOscHomeUrl" DefaultValue="https://customer-pod.domain.com/index.html"/>
                <bt:Url id="residOscHomeEditUrl" DefaultValue="https://customer-pod.domain.com/index.html?rc_channel=COMPOSE"/>
            </bt:Urls>
            <bt:ShortStrings>
                <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="App Name"/>
                <bt:String id="buttonLabel" DefaultValue="App Name"/>
                <bt:String id="superTipTitle" DefaultValue="Click this to launch the Application"/>
            </bt:ShortStrings>
            <bt:LongStrings>
                <bt:String id="groupTooltip" DefaultValue="App actions"/>
                <bt:String id="buttonTooltip" DefaultValue="Launches Application"/>
                <bt:String id="superTipDescription" DefaultValue="Launches Application"/>
            </bt:LongStrings>
        </Resources>
        <VersionOverrides xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/mailappversionoverrides/1.1"
                          xsi:type="VersionOverridesV1_1">
            <Hosts>
                <Host xsi:type="MailHost">
                    <DesktopFormFactor>
                        <FunctionFile resid="functionFile"/>
                        <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageReadCommandSurface">
                            <OfficeTab id="TabDefaultRead">
                                <Group id="oscReadGroup">
                                    <Label resid="groupLabel"/>
                                    <Tooltip resid="groupTooltip"/>

                                    <Control xsi:type="Button" id="oscReadButton">
                                        <Label resid="buttonLabel"/>
                                        <Tooltip resid="buttonTooltip"/>
                                        <Supertip>
                                            <Title resid="superTipTitle"/>
                                            <Description resid="superTipDescription"/>
                                        </Supertip>
                                        <Icon>
                                            <bt:Image size="16" resid="osc_icon_16x16"/>
                                            <bt:Image size="32" resid="osc_icon_32x32"/>
                                            <bt:Image size="80" resid="osc_icon_80x80"/>
                                        </Icon>
                                        <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                            <SourceLocation resid="residOscHomeUrl"/>
                                            <SupportsPinning>true</SupportsPinning>
                                        </Action>
                                    </Control>
                                </Group>
                            </OfficeTab>
                        </ExtensionPoint>
                        <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="MessageComposeCommandSurface">
                            <OfficeTab id="TabDefaultCompose">
                                <Group id="oscComposeGroup">
                                    <Label resid="groupLabel"/>
                                    <Tooltip resid="groupTooltip"/>

                                    <Control xsi:type="Button" id="oscComposeButton">
                                        <Label resid="buttonLabel"/>
                                        <Tooltip resid="buttonTooltip"/>
                                        <Supertip>
                                            <Title resid="superTipTitle"/>
                                            <Description resid="superTipDescription"/>
                                        </Supertip>
                                        <Icon>
                                            <bt:Image size="16" resid="osc_icon_16x16"/>
                                            <bt:Image size="32" resid="osc_icon_32x32"/>
                                            <bt:Image size="80" resid="osc_icon_80x80"/>
                                        </Icon>
                                        <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                            <SourceLocation resid="residOscHomeEditUrl"/>
                                            <SupportsPinning>true</SupportsPinning>
                                        </Action>
                                    </Control>
                                </Group>
                            </OfficeTab>
                        </ExtensionPoint>
                        <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentAttendeeCommandSurface">
                            <OfficeTab id="TabDefaultApptRead">
                                <Group id="oscApptReadGroup">
                                    <Label resid="groupLabel"/>
                                    <Tooltip resid="groupTooltip"/>

                                    <Control xsi:type="Button" id="oscApptReadButton">
                                        <Label resid="buttonLabel"/>
                                        <Tooltip resid="buttonTooltip"/>
                                        <Supertip>
                                            <Title resid="superTipTitle"/>
                                            <Description resid="superTipDescription"/>
                                        </Supertip>
                                        <Icon>
                                            <bt:Image size="16" resid="osc_icon_16x16"/>
                                            <bt:Image size="32" resid="osc_icon_32x32"/>
                                            <bt:Image size="80" resid="osc_icon_80x80"/>
                                        </Icon>
                                        <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                            <SourceLocation resid="residOscHomeUrl"/>
                                            <SupportsPinning>true</SupportsPinning>
                                        </Action>
                                    </Control>
                                </Group>
                            </OfficeTab>
                        </ExtensionPoint>
                        <ExtensionPoint xsi:type="AppointmentOrganizerCommandSurface">
                            <OfficeTab id="TabDefaultApptCompose">
                                <Group id="oscApptComposeGroup">
                                    <Label resid="groupLabel"/>
                                    <Tooltip resid="groupTooltip"/>

                                    <Control xsi:type="Button" id="oscApptComposeButton">
                                        <Label resid="buttonLabel"/>
                                        <Tooltip resid="buttonTooltip"/>
                                        <Supertip>
                                            <Title resid="superTipTitle"/>
                                            <Description resid="superTipDescription"/>
                                        </Supertip>
                                        <Icon>
                                            <bt:Image size="16" resid="osc_icon_16x16"/>
                                            <bt:Image size="32" resid="osc_icon_32x32"/>
                                            <bt:Image size="80" resid="osc_icon_80x80"/>
                                        </Icon>
                                        <Action xsi:type="ShowTaskpane">
                                            <SourceLocation resid="residOscHomeEditUrl"/>
                                            <SupportsPinning>true</SupportsPinning>
                                        </Action>
                                    </Control>
                                </Group>
                            </OfficeTab>
                        </ExtensionPoint>
                    </DesktopFormFactor>
                </Host>
            </Hosts>
            <Resources>
                <bt:Images>
                    <bt:Image id="osc_icon_16x16"
                              DefaultValue="https://customer-pod.domain.com/css/images/osc_icon_16.png"/>
                    <bt:Image id="osc_icon_32x32"
                              DefaultValue="https://customer-pod.domain.com/css/images/osc_icon_32.png"/>
                    <bt:Image id="osc_icon_80x80"
                              DefaultValue="https://customer-pod.domain.com/css/images/osc_icon_80.png"/>
                </bt:Images>
                <bt:Urls>
                    <bt:Url id="residOscHomeUrl"
                            DefaultValue="https://customer-pod.domain.com/index.html"/>
                    <bt:Url id="residOscHomeEditUrl"
                            DefaultValue="https://customer-pod.domain.com/index.html?rc_channel=COMPOSE"/>
                </bt:Urls>
                <bt:ShortStrings>
                    <bt:String id="groupLabel" DefaultValue="App Name"/>
                    <bt:String id="buttonLabel" DefaultValue="App Name"/>
                    <bt:String id="superTipTitle" DefaultValue="Click this to launch Application"/>
                </bt:ShortStrings>
                <bt:LongStrings>
                    <bt:String id="groupTooltip" DefaultValue="Application actions"/>
                    <bt:String id="buttonTooltip" DefaultValue="Launches Application"/>
                    <bt:String id="superTipDescription" DefaultValue="Launches Application"/>
                </bt:LongStrings>
            </Resources>
        </VersionOverrides>
    </VersionOverrides>
</OfficeApp>
```

Comment: Do you see the taskpane open at all? if so, what's loaded in the taskpane? Could you also share your outlook build number and your add-in manifest for us to test this out?

Comment: The task pane opens up as usual and we see the blue dot loading icon. After a time, where we would usually expect the loading icon to switch to document load, a new IE window is opened instead. The task pane still shows the loading icon.

Comment: Is there an email address we could pass the manifest to? I don't see a way to attach here.

Comment: You could i believe paste your manifest as a text by editing your original post and we'll copy from that.

Comment: Try installing the updates. And most importantly even though office.onready is new function and is recommended. Try the office.initialize on your load. May be this will solve.

Comment: We haven't not switched to Office.onready yet. Our customer code is still using office.initialize

Comment: I've added the manifest that we use to the original post

Comment: Your manifest looks good. Assuming this may be bcoz of the windows updates on some customer machine. I will leave it MSFT for their response. But on the customer machine once your add-in is opened try hitting the `ctrl + f5` and see if the issue persist

Comment: @HarshaVardhanGopalan are you doing any redirects on your home page to a different domain? if so make sure you add the domains on the AppDomains element in your manifest. that will keep the page in the task pane. can you please try that?

Comment: Facing same issue. @MSFT. Any update on this ?

Comment: @user11402261. Is this issue fixed for you

Comment: I had a similar issue and found that this was because of the <AppDomain>https://localhost/someLocalSite</AppDomain>
Changing this to <AppDomain>https://localhost/</AppDomain>
seemed to work for development environment